# Проблема с glassfish-web.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, java-ee, glassfish

У меня проблема с передачей русских символов из формы на другую страницу. Выглядит так: **Ð¾Ð»Ð»**. На всех страница стоит UTF-8.

Я так понимаю моя проблема кроется тут, и это из-за GlassFish.

[image: Проблема]

Я пытаюсь создать glassfish-web.xml (тут ли он должен лежать?)

[image: Структура проекта]

И что в нём писать, если у меня GlassFish 4.0?

Пока в нём это:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN"
        "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
    <glassfish-web-app>
        <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
    </glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Не знаю где glassfish-web.xml должен находиться в iiideeiiee, но в готовом приложении он должен оказаться в WEB-INF (рядом с web.xml)

Answer (score 4):

Перемести `glassfish-web.xml` в папку WEB-INF